# Finding $\lim_{x \to 1, y \to 0} \frac{\ln(x+e^y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have no Ideas how to approach this.

> Find $$\lim_{x \to 1, y \to 0} \frac{\ln(x+e^y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$

Advice? Hints?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substituting in $x=1,y=0:$ we get $$\frac{\ln(1+e^0)}{\sqrt{1+0}} = \ln 2$$

Comment: Oops, seems I just overthinked possible solutions, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Just substitute in $x=1,y=0$ to get $\frac{\ln(1+e^0)}{\sqrt{1+0}} = \ln 2.$